# My app is in pending review since month

Tags: software-center, application-submission

I wrote a desktop app "titania" registered it under https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/dev/apps/. Now month are gone and it is still in pending review with the notice for the new coming upload process.

The details to Titania are under
https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/dev/apps/2136/

What can I do? Is this the right place to publish. Are there any news.

Comment: On the page you linked yourself, see the warning message: "Thank you for submitting a gratis Free Software application through MyApps. At this time we are unable to process this request, as we are working on the implementation of a new app upload process.

To get your software out to millions of Ubuntu users in the meantime, you can either use a Personal Package Archive to distribute your app for free, or you can define a price to charge for your app."

Answer (score 0):

Change the license from GNU GPL v3 into proprietary. You can copy and paste the GPL 3's text into your own terms if you still want it to be a free software.

Now your app will be approved in a few days (I hope).